# Store big Set of Data in Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, bigdata

Does anyone know how to efficiently store a row like this in a database if the data is recurring? Say, the first 2 values are the reference, and the following ones are values that are similar to the first value.

The problem is that each row has a different length, because for each first value, there are different other values that are similar to the first. Therefore, it would not be very efficient to simply create more columns.

As a small example:

The first value up to ; is the reference value. After that always comes a comparison operator. Then comes the second value, again a comparison operator and an additional info. Then again a value, comparison operator, additional info.

Depending on how many values are similar, the more are attached to a line.

**3500312;09**;4217558;01;1;3780576;01;1;3909811;03;1;3909952;03;1;3911386;05;1;3909343;06;1;3909604;07;1;3908651;08;1

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understand your question correctly, but it looks like you best store this by repeating the reference value and reference comparisons like this:

| ref_value | ref_comparison | value | comparison | additional_info |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3500312 | 09 | 4217558 | 01 | 1 |
| 3500312 | 09 | 3780576 | 01 | 1 |
| 3500312 | 09 | 3909811 | 03 | 1 |
| 3500312 | 09 | .. | .. | .. |
| 3500312 | 09 | .. | .. | .. |
| 3500312 | 09 | .. | .. | .. |

Comment: If the order of the values is significant it would be worth adding an ordering key